# emmeans - estimates for levels of variable

Tags: r, regression, emmeans

With this model:

```
library(emmeans)
mod <- lm(conc~source + percent, data=pigs)

emmeans(mod, "percent")
 percent emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
    12.9   37.6 0.93 25     35.7     39.6
```

I'm using the `emmeans` package, and it gives me the estimate for the average of `percent`. But what if I want to predict the `percent` values `8`, `10` and `13`? How can I specify that in the `emmeans` call?

Comment: what package is that from?

Comment: @markhogue, sorry, it's emmeans. I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    newrg <- ref_grid(mod, at = list(source = c("fish", "soy", "skim"), percent = c(8, 10, 15)))
    predict(newrg, interval = "prediction", by = "percent")

    plot(newrg, PIs = TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. `source` is a factor with three levels: `fish` `soy` `skim`. `emmeans(mod, "percent")` averages over the levels of `source`, is there a way to do the same using your solution?

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, I'm getting a `Error in X[, nm, drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds`. Does the code run with you?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise that it is a package dataset. Updated.